# Issue with tracing down the array in Java recursion function

Tags: java, string, algorithm, recursion

I have an issue with recursion in Java. The question is as such:

Given n pairs of parentheses, write a function to generate all combinations of well-formed parentheses.

For example, given `n = 3`, a solution set is:

The code for the above problem is recursive and is as mentioned below:

```
public List<String> generateParenthesis(int n) {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    dfs(result, "", n, n);
    return result;
}

public void dfs(ArrayList<String> result, String s, int left, int right){
    if(left > right)
        return;

    if(left==0&&right==0){
        result.add(s);
        return;
    }

    if(left>0){
        dfs(result, s+"(", left-1, right);
    }

    if(right>0){
        dfs(result, s+")", left, right-1);
    }
}
```

I have been able to trace the program upto a particular point, but I am unable to trace it down totally.

if n=2

```
left=2;right=2;
result="(())", 
__________
| s=""   |
| l=2    |
| r=2    |
|        |
|        |
|________|
    |
    V
__________  
| s=(    |
| l 1    |
| r 2    |
|        |
|        |
|________|
    |
    V
__________
| s=((   |
| l 0    |
| r 2    |
|        |
|        |
|________|
    |
    V
__________
| s=(()  |
| l 0    |
| r 1    |
|        |
|        |
|________|
    |
    V
__________  
| s= (())|
| l=0    |
| r=0    |
|        |
|        |
|________|
```

how would the program work after what I have mentioned above? Can someone help me tracing it? Thanks.

Comment: Do you **have** to use recursion?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "**tracing**" -- "Can someone help me _tracing_ it?", "able to _trace_ the program" etc.  Trace/Tracing is usually used to mean _debugging_, and you don't seem to be talking about debugging.

Comment: Good question..i'm learning recursion at this point in time..and had similar doubts even while solving other problems. Thought it would be a good idea to know what's happening here. Thanks

Comment: I think you can solve this problem really easily without using recursion.

Comment: Gooz, the issue is not with trying to solve the problem with/without using recursion..I am trying to understand how recursion works. This is just an example that I am using. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From where you left off:

```
__________
| s=(    |
| l=1    |
| r=2    |
|        |
|        |
|________|
    |
    V
__________  
| s=()   |
| l 1    |
| r 1    |
|        |
|        |
|________|
    |
    V
__________
| s=()(  |
| l 0    |
| r 1    |
|        |
|        |
|________|
    |
    V
__________
| s=()() |
| l 0    |
| r 0    |
|        |
|        |
|________|
```

If you're using eclipse or any other IDE, it should be easy to set a breakpoint and go through how your program runs line by line (showing all your variables and how they change). If you haven't learned debugging yet, I would encourage you to google it and learn how to debug programs.

What your program is actually doing:

```
left (l=1, r=2)
  left (l=0, r=2)
    right (l=0, r=1)
      right (l=0, r=0)
        add result to s (l=0, r=0)
    *here you break out of 3 recursive functions and values of l,r reset to (l=1, r=2)*
  right (l=1, r=1)
    left (l=0, r=1)
      right (l=0, r=0)
      add result to s (l=0, r=0)
```

Comment: I can't comment on your post because I am a new user here:

The reason why this calls right instead of left is because when you break out of the previous recursive call, you have already called left in the that recursive call so it will go (right -> left -> right) instead of (left -> right -> right)

Comment: Fantastic...thanks a lot for your explanation. Appreciate it.